# Properties of Partial Derivatives

Tags: calculus, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx = xdx.$$ Is it true that $$\int \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx = \frac{x^2}{2} \implies \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{x^2}{2} \implies f = \frac{x^3}{6}?$$ Assuming all constants of integration are zero?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $df(x,y) = f_x(x,y)\,dx = x\,dx$ implies that for some function $g(y)$, $f(x,y) = x^2/2 + g(y)$.

The implication
$$
\int f_x(x,y)\,dx = \frac{x^2}{2}\implies f_x(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{2}
$$
is false.

Answer (score 1):

1) If you do a check, you will see that the answer is wrong:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial (\frac {x^3}{6})}{\partial x} = \frac{x^2}{2}$$
Plug it into the original equation:
$$\frac{x^2}{2}dx\neq xdx$$
Hence, your answer is not correct.

2) If all constants of integration are zeros, then $f$ is not a function of two variables $x$ and $y$, but only a function of one variable $x$ (It is because the constant of integration of integral $\int \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx$ must have the form of $f(y) + const$. And if it is zero, then $f(y)$ is either zero or constant; which in both cases implies that $f$ doesn't depend on $y$). In this case you can merely strike out $dx$ on the left hand side of the original equation and solve a simple ODE.